# pythonic version of SQL MAX case when

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

Given the code below what would be a better more pythonic way of achieving this. The sql syntax is just for reference.  df has many months of flags but just want it to be pivoted table as once ever. Thanks

```
     SELECT distinct x.ID
    ,max(case when x.Yes=1 THEN 'Yes' else null) as Yes
    ,max(case when x.No=1 THEN 'No' else null) as No
     FROM df X
     GROUP BY  x.ID
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you connecting python to? Why would the posted SQL not be 'pythonic'?

Comment: trying to find a way to write this in python....not sql

Comment: So you just need to build a string? Then what do you plan to do with the SQL string? Not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How does one perform this pivoted groupby distinct query in python?

Comment: That may depend on the RDBMS python is connecting to. For SQLServer review https://www.sqlshack.com/python-scripts-for-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby([id], as_index=False).agg({'Yes': 'max','No': 'max'})
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of how this code works, it will improve this answer and probably be more beneficial to OP.